# Replace occurrences in NSString with those in an NSArray

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray, nslog

I'm looking for a quick way to debug my SQLite queries in an iOS app. I have something like this:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithString: @"SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = ? AND bar = ?"]; 
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"baz", @"bat", nil];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", sql, params);
```

I'd like to know if there is a one or two-liner to replace the question marks with the params to make the output more readable. I'm ***not*** looking for something that outputs valid sql but rather something easier to read than my current NSLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface NSString (SQLQueryDebugging)
- (NSString *)stringBySubstitutingParameters:(NSArray *)params forInstancesOfPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder;
@end

@implementation NSString (SQLQueryDebugging)

- (NSString *)stringBySubstitutingParameters:(NSArray *)params forInstancesOfPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder
{
    NSString *composedQuery = self;
    NSRange substitutionRange = [composedQuery rangeOfString:placeholder];
    NSInteger parameterIndex = 0;
    while(substitutionRange.length != 0)
    {
        NSString *currentParam = [params objectAtIndex:parameterIndex];
        composedQuery = [composedQuery stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:substitutionRange withString:currentParam];
        ++parameterIndex;
        NSInteger lastSubstitutionIndex = substitutionRange.location + [currentParam length];
        NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(lastSubstitutionIndex, [composedQuery length] - lastSubstitutionIndex);
        substitutionRange = [composedQuery rangeOfString:placeholder options:0 range:searchRange];
    }

    return composedQuery;
}
```

Drop that in somewhere, then you can get what you want with:

```
NSString *completeSQL = [sql stringBySubstitutingParameters:params forInstancesOfPlaceholder:@"?"];
```

Comment: As a beginning Objective-C developer I haven't had the chance to really use Categories for much. This is a great example! I had to modify it a little bit to add a check for when currentParam is an NSNumber. Since this always expects a string, it will crash. Other than that, it's a perfect one-liner! Thanks!

Comment: Glad this worked for you. I thought about the case where you might have non-string parameters and almost suggested that you use `[currentParam description]` instead of `currentParam` where appropriate. Glad you figured it out on your own :)